# start browser with specicfic user profile using chromedp

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, testing, go, browser-automation

i am using selenium with python and i can do all my testing work using it
but i am learning **Golang** and i want to try to test using it
i came across 
**chromedp** [the chromedp github repo](https://github.com/knq/chromedp)
 and i like it but
i couldn't figure out how to start google chrome with a specific user profile

can any one help please ?

i am using this example :

```
    package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "time"

    cdp "github.com/knq/chromedp"
    cdptypes "github.com/knq/chromedp/cdp"
)

func main() {
    var err error

    // create context
    ctxt, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    // create chrome instance
    c, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithLog(log.Printf))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // run task list
    var site, res string
    err = c.Run(ctxt, googleSearch("site:brank.as", "Easy Money Management", &site, &res))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // shutdown chrome
    err = c.Shutdown(ctxt)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // wait for chrome to finish
    err = c.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Printf("saved screenshot of #testimonials from search result listing `%s` (%s)", res, site)
}

func googleSearch(q, text string, site, res *string) cdp.Tasks {
    var buf []byte
    sel := fmt.Sprintf(`//a[text()[contains(., '%s')]]`, text)
    return cdp.Tasks{
        cdp.Navigate(`https://www.google.com`),
        cdp.Sleep(2 * time.Second),
        cdp.WaitVisible(`#hplogo`, cdp.ByID),
        cdp.SendKeys(`#lst-ib`, q+"\n", cdp.ByID),
        cdp.WaitVisible(`#res`, cdp.ByID),
        cdp.Text(sel, res),
        cdp.Click(sel),
        cdp.Sleep(2 * time.Second),
        cdp.WaitVisible(`#footer`, cdp.ByQuery),
        cdp.WaitNotVisible(`div.v-middle > div.la-ball-clip-rotate`, cdp.ByQuery),
        cdp.Location(site),
        cdp.Screenshot(`#testimonials`, &buf, cdp.ByID),
        cdp.ActionFunc(func(context.Context, cdptypes.Handler) error {
            return ioutil.WriteFile("testimonials.png", buf, 0644)
        }),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the runner options for this

```
cdp, err := cdp.New(ctxt, cdp.WithRunnerOptions(
            runner.UserDataDir("<your path>"),
        ))
```

You can look for all available options at below link

https://github.com/knq/chromedp/blob/dc08ecc7272dd745adc3494fb675c76174cbb2b3/runner/runner.go

Comment: i tried it but all it did is to open a new tap in my browser and then prints a timeout error . could you plz give me an example of the user path profile in linux ? maybe i am doing something wrong . mine is like /home/.config/google-chrome/Default/

Comment: Can you kill all chrome processes and then try?

Comment: i did and i figured out that it creates the directory i give to the folder of my source program and still not opening my profile

Comment: what path are you using? And you want to launch it using an existing profile?

Comment: i was pointing to the Profile 1 in my google-chrome config folder and that was wrong i made it point to the root of the google chrome and it worked nice . thx for your help

Comment: For that is another parameter which needs to be used `--profile-directory`. This in combination with the UserDataDir.

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple 'profiles' in the user data directory you can also specify the name of the profile directory you want to use:

```
opts := []chromedp.ExecAllocatorOption{
        chromedp.UserDataDir(`...\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data`),
        chromedp.Flag("profile-directory", "Profile 1"), // <-- like this
        ...
```